# Is the KeyStore encrypted by default?

Tags: c#, android, encryption, xamarin.android, keystore

I currently have some code that stores my sensitive information in the `KeyStore` like so:

```
static readonly char[] Password = null;

//Create KeyStore
ks = KeyStore.GetInstance(KeyStore.DefaultType);
prot = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(Password);

//AddUserName
var alias = MakeAlias("UserName", serviceId);
var usernameSecretKey = new SecretAccount(username);
var usernameEntry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(usernameSecretKey);
ks.SetEntry(alias, usernameEntry, prot);
```

now this has got `PasswordProtection` but the password is `null`.

Pulling my `Keystore` file off the device I can see the data is encrypted (not in plain text). But is this data encrypted enough or is it simple by decrypting by calling something like `File.Decrypty(password = null);`

Comment: you can all the features of Keystore from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keystore is not encrypted by default but it contains the encrypted key information with it, which is password protected

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand "it contains the encrypted key information with it which is password protected" means. Could you give an example?

Comment: @user1: The keystore may contain public certificates, private keys, and secret keys. Only the private keys are certificates are encrypted, with a password that you are required to supply. In addition, the entire keystore is integrity checked (but not encrypted) using a MAC whose key is generated from a password.